# Adding an overlay view to UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a transparent `UINavigationBar` set with `appearance`, no subclass involved.

I want to add a view that will "act" as the `UINavigationBar`'s background, this view also has an expand/collapse custom search bar (no a subclass of `UISearchBar`). I will call this view an OverlayView.

The reason for this is mostly because the background color should change dynamically.

I have added my OverlayView as a subview of `UINavigationBar`. It displays correctly and It does everything I need. But I when I tap the search text field it won't pick up the tap, i.e. I can't type anything in the search field.

I have `userInteractionEnabled` set to `YES` on both my OverlayView and the `UINavigationBar`.

Should I add my OverlayView elsewhere? How can I get the taps on that view to be recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this that may help you.

```
UISearchBar *searchBar = [UISearchBar new];
searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
[searchBar sizeToFit];
[searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
UIView * OverlayView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:searchBar.bounds];
[OverlayView addSubview:searchBar];
self.navigationItem.titleView = OverlayView;
```

Answer (score 0):

I subclassed UINavigationBar for drawing custom background layer.
Probably, my code will help you

```
#import "OCNavigationBar.h"
#define UIColorFromRGB(rgbValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]

#define UIColorFromRGBAlpha(rgbValue, alphaValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((rgbValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(rgbValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:alphaValue]


@implementation OCNavigationBar {
    UIView * gradientView;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (gradientView == NULL) {
        CGFloat statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
        CGRect gradientRect = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, - statusBarHeight, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height + statusBarHeight);

        gradientView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:gradientRect];
        gradientView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        UIColor * gradientColor1 = UIColorFromRGB(0x242430);
        UIColor * gradientColor2 = UIColorFromRGB(0x252532);

        CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        gradient.frame = CGRectMake(gradientRect.origin.x, 0, gradientRect.size.width, gradientRect.size.height);
        gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[gradientColor1 CGColor], (id)[gradientColor2 CGColor], nil];
        [gradientView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

        [self insertSubview:gradientView atIndex:-1];
    }
}

#pragma mark - Tools

- (void)insertSubview:(UIView *)view atIndex:(NSInteger)index
{
    [super insertSubview:view atIndex:index+1];
}
```